# Name Servers not found from some machines

Tags: domain-name-system, email, outlook

My website, pandlstrategies.com, comes up fine on some machines.  On others it is timing out.  On my partners PC, who is located in Arkansas, everything is working fine and she is getting email.

On my machine regardless of whether I am at home or at the office, I can not reach my domain and in Outlook it gives me the error message name server not found.

When I go to yahoo mail as well as gmail and live mail, I can download my email from the pandlstrategies.com mail server just fine, but I cant get it through Outlook.

At the office my co workers are also unable to load my domain as they get the time out error too. I had other people check the domain from their offices and they too can get to my website.

What is going on?
 This is really a major problem for me.

Comment: When was this setup? If it was in the last day, wait another day, then call the hosting company's support.

Comment: six years ago....

Comment: Looks like there was an update yesterday so you'd probably right Chris.

Comment: Chris what do you mean?

Comment: I have flushed the DNS, released and renewed with ipconfig, can  reach the server through web email programs, but cant connect to my site or other sites hosted by the same company.  Others are having no problems whatsoever so I am not sure where to look or what actions to take.  My host company says he can see himself fine and doesnt see any problems on that end.

Comment: I took the third name server out as the host said maybe that is causing the problems, but no result.  SO yesterday I put the third name server back in thinking maybe it would resolve it. That is probably the change you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

On both a working and a non-working machine call up a command prompt and type in 'nslookup pandlstrategies.com' and press enter, you should get something like this;

> C:>nslookup pandlstrategies.com
>   Server:  something.something Address: 
>   132.146.70.61
>
> Non-authoritative answer: Name:
>   pandlstrategies.com Address: 
>   **66.185.28.159**

On a working machine you should see the same number as I have shown in **bold**, on a non-working machine you may get a different number or an error message.

On the non-working machine now type in 'ipconfig /flushdns' and press enter - then try the same nslookup line from above - does it work now?

If not then it's either that there's been a change made recently that hasn't propagated around the internet or more likely they have a problem with their own DNS server. If this latter problem appears to be the case then it's not going to be easy to fix as it'll take work at each non-working-machine's DNS server.

Comment: nslookup pandlstrategies.com returns:209.18.47.61

Comment: i get dns-cac-1b-01.rr.com 209.18.47.61 even after flushdns

Comment: ok now I got the right address, but request timed out after two seconds

Comment: That's your DNS server, not the IP of pandlstrategies, is there a second IP address below that one? you can always cut and paste all of the output here if this helps.

Comment: which request, the ping?

Comment: nslookup pandsltraegies.com

Comment: dumb question here how do i cut and paste out of the command line screen?  doesnt let me do it the way i would normally

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe you'd be better off dealing with our collegues over on superuser.com - we're here for more sysadmin-type issues, this is turning more into a general PC usage issue and they're better at that.

Comment: nslookup pandlstrategies.com    server: pandlstrategies.com   address:  66.185.28.159   dns request timed out.  time out was 2 seconds. request to pandlstrategies.com timed-out

Comment: so one of your DNS servers is working - otherwise you wouldn't get the 28.159, but the others aren't - remove the ones that aren't and try browsing to the site.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a name server problem.

Run a WHOIS on your domain and take note of the name servers that are listed for your domain. Query each of the name servers listed by WHOIS for the NS records for your domain and make sure they each return the same servers listed by WHOIS. If the WHOIS lookup lists servers that your name servers don't list then you need to fix your WHOIS information. If your name servers list name servers that WHOIS doesn't list then you need to fix your name servers.

Basically, the WHOIS lookup and your name servers should "agree" on which servers are name servers for your domain.

Answer (score 0):

This domain, pandlstrategies.com, have only two name servers and, from the closeness of their IP addresses, they seem located in the same room. Although they seem to work fine as of today, this is a very brittle setup. If there is even a small routing problem, the clients will not be able to reach one of the name servers. I strongly suggest you get a better service.